# Fail to load manifest error

Tags: visual-c++

What does this message means? How to solve this error?

```
Error   1   general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.   ..\DebugObj\Example1\Example1.exe.intermediate.manifest Example1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a project I inherited from a pre-2008 Visual studio.
It was not practical for me to add a Main function as sugested by the previous answer.  I googled for a while but could not find the root of the problem.

A friend of mine gave me the following solution.
It turns out that the old project included a "example.manifest" file entry in the Resource File Folder in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer for the project.  When trying to build the project, VS 2008 was trying to load "example.manifest", which did not exist on the new 2008 folder structor (it was not needed).

So the solution was as simple as removing the entry "example.manifest" from the Resouce Files folder.  Rebuilt, and no more errors!.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

to fix that error you need to have an entry point in your solution.

just create a main.cpp with a main method... just like this.

in "main.cpp"

```
    void main(){}
```

then compile and it will get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue myself. Converted a VS2005 project to VS2010.

I was using the option, Linker -> Manifest File -> Additional Manifest Dependencies: type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'

The conversion garbled it into type=%27win32%27...etc

Fixing this option to the correct format, type='win32'..etc resolved the issue.  But not before I accidentally used the format, type=win32...etc  and received the same error.